# Formatting a string to find and replace a segment

Tags: java, string

I have the following string in Java.

```
String abc="My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:199999' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst";
```

I want to that the no. followed by  `MNT+2` and then colon(:) i.e. 199999 in the above case should be replaced by 1  and rest of the string should remain same.

i.e.
O/p should be `"My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:1' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst"`

2nd eg. >> 
If input string is `"ABC : MNT+232421:9' MNT+39191: hks"`

O/P should be `"ABC : MNT+232421:1' MNT+39191: hks"`

I tried many things but can't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regular expression: `(MNT\+\d+):\d+'` and use this replacement string: `$1:1'`.

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/eF6nA9/1

Answer (score 0):

use replaceAll()

```
String abc="My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:199999' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst";

abc = abc.replaceAll("\\d+'","1'");

System.out.print(abc); //My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:1' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a few grouping expressions, something like

```
String[] arr = { "My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:199999' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst",
        "ABC : MNT+232421:9' MNT+39191: hks" };
String[] out = { "My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:1' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst",
        "ABC : MNT+232421:1' MNT+39191: hks" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*):(\\d+)'(.*)");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(arr[i]);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String t = m.group(1) + ":1'" + m.group(3);
        System.out.printf("%s = %s %s%n", t, out[i], t.equals(out[i]));
    }
}
```

Output is (as requested, but formatted for this post)

```
My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:1' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst = 
    My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:1' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst true
ABC : MNT+232421:1' MNT+39191: hks = 
    ABC : MNT+232421:1' MNT+39191: hks true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll()` using a regular expression,

```
String abc="My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:199999' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst";
abc.replaceAll("(MNT\\+\\d+):\\d+'", "$1:1'")
```

It will replace all occurrences of the given pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution is the simpler/cleaner one but for the sake of comparison let's take a look at a different way.

```
String abc="My name 233:23 is Shefali MNT+2:199999' MNT+12:40 xyzpqrst";

//get index of the start of first "MNT"
int mntIndex = abc.indexOf("MNT+2:");

//get index of the second "MNT" location
int mntIndex2 = abc.indexOf("' MNT", mntIndex);

//now set abc equal to a substring up to the end of "MNT+2:"
//adding 6 (the length of "MNT+2:")
//manually adding "1" 
//finishing with a substring of abc starting 
//from the "' MNT" index up to the end of abc (abc.length())
abc = abc.substring(0, mntIndex) + 1 + abc.substring(mntIndex2,abc.length());
```